# Como setar SSL no cookie e exibir no navegador?

Tags: php, cookies, https

Meu site no local usa SSL, carrego por `https://`, então, ele deveria setar o protocolo SSL, minha dúvida é porque quando acesso pelo console do Chrome, em Application > Storage > Cookies, onde tem o cookie, o item `Secure` não está checado como os cookies remotos do google por exemplo?

```
public function renewCookiePublic($token,$user)
{

     $protocoloSSL = FALSE;
     if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') || 
        (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')) {
            $protocoloSSL = TRUE;  
     }

     setrawcookie("_token_access", $token, time()+10800,'/', '',  $protocoloSSL); 
     setrawcookie("_user_access", trim($user), time()+10800,'/', '',  $protocoloSSL); 

 }
```

Comment: Veja [isso](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente eu não usaria:

```
isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'
```

Isso pode ser manipulado facilmente, já que vem via headers da requisição HTTP, podendo ser usado por algum servidor com alguma configuração em cima do Fast-CGI no próprio back-end, ainda sim ela pode ser envia via "front-end", o que poderiam fraudar facilmente a requisição fazendo algo assim:

```
curl -i -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" http://site/teste
```

Na verdade ele é mais usado para um "controle" de "proxy" como https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/#how-to-use-it-in-nginx, mas realmente se o `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` não esta "populado" creio que seja uma má configuração no "proxy reverso" ou "load balancer", eu não entendo muito.

Esses headers (de Forwarded) se eu não me engano são voltados pra configurações nestes tipos de "proxies" (tudo no servidor apenas) e não deveriam ser expostos ao cliente e nem ser misturado com o que vem do lado cliente, mas muita gente configura nas coxas isso.

Posso estar enganado, mas do que entendo de servidores, se estiver tudo configurado ok **só** isso sempre deve funcionar:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
   ...
}
```

No seu script não vai "afetar", porque na verdade ele esta meio sem sentido, o próprio uso da IF esta desnecessário (mas isso vou falar mais abaixo)

---

### Sobre o problema do cookie sem HTTPS

Tem que ter certeza de que você não criou acidentalmente já os cookies fora do HTTPS, porque ai será outra coisa, agora se tratando de setar no momento que acessa HTTPS

Porque pelo seu código, se executar **com HTTPS** e **sem HTTPS** os cookies vão ser gerados sempre, então provavelmente ambos existem, se a intenção é só autenticar em HTTPS então apenas isto bastaria:

```
public function renewCookiePublic($token,$user)
{
     setrawcookie("_token_access", $token, time()+10800, '/', '', true);
     setrawcookie("_user_access", trim($user), time()+10800, '/', '', true);
}
```

Nem precisaria checar se é HTTPS, porque como a propria documentação diz sobre o quinto parametro da função setcookie e setrawcookie:

> Indica que o cookie só poderá ser transmitido sob uma conexão segura HTTPS do cliente. Quando configurado para `TRUE`, o cookie será enviado **SOMENTE** se uma conexão segura existir. No lado do servidor, fica por conta do programador enviar esse tipo de cookie somente sob uma conexão segura (ex respeitando `$_SERVER["HTTPS"]`).

Então provavelmente no teu storage existe o cookie sem HTTPS checado porque você realmente gerou, seja por ter acessado sem HTTPS e depois com HTTPS ou por simplesmente esta tua IF talvez estiver errada e o teu servidor Apache ou Ngnix estiver configurado errado.